# Anomalous decimal places in python after list-to-numpy-to-list

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, python-2.7

Executing the following code in a fresh Python 2.7.3 interpreter on my ubuntu linux machine gives the output shown after the code.

```
import numpy as np
p = [1/3., 1/2., 23/25., 1]
q = np.array(p)
r = list(q)
print p; print q; print r
```

Output:

```
[0.3333333333333333, 0.5, 0.92, 1]
[ 0.33333333  0.5         0.92        1.        ]
[0.33333333333333331, 0.5, 0.92000000000000004, 1.0]
```

I'm trying to figure out why p and r print out differently, but so far haven't got a plausible theory.  Any ideas on why they differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They print differently because `p` is a list of `float` and `int`, whereas `r` is a list of `numpy.float64`:

```
In [23]: map(type, p)
Out[23]: [float, float, float, int]

In [24]: map(type, r)
Out[24]: [numpy.float64, numpy.float64, numpy.float64, numpy.float64]
```

This happens because NumPy arrays are of a uniform type, so everything gets widened to `float64` when you create `q`.

The values in two lists compare equal, so it's purely a difference in formatting:

```
In [22]: p == r
Out[22]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a difference in how `__repr__` is implemented for a `np.float64` vs. a python `float`.

When you create a list out of your numpy array, you take the elements (with type `np.float64`) and put them in the list.  So you have actually converted the types of your original data from `float` to `np.float64`.